# SingleTagSectionHandler returned as DefaultSection

Tags: vb.net, app-config, system.configuration

I have an App.conf file which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="CrystalReport" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <CrystalReport Database="Test" />

</configuration>
```

As you can see an CrystalReport section is defined in the configSections.
But when I do: config.GetSection("CrystalReport") its returning an DefaultSection object in stead of an SingleTagSectionHandler.

How do I retrieve the Database attribute from the CrystalReport tag using the ConfigurationManager?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the static [**ConfigurationManager.GetSection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx):

```
Dim config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CrystalReport")
```